# Is it possible to 'assert' a type using .where()?

Tags: dart

I have a `list<Components> components;` which is sub-class of `Bonus`, hence `Bonus` are `Components` too.

The `.toRect()` method is defined in the `Bonus` class but not in the `Components` class.

I'm making sure I'm only calling `.toRect()` in Bonus objects, so there should be no problem, but Dart is keeping me from running the code with the following error:

> The method 'toRect' isn't defined for the type 'Component'.

Is there a way to go around this problem without the need to define `.toRect()` on the `Components` Class?

```
  void checkForCollision() {
    controller.components.where((c) => c is Bonus).forEach((bonus) {
      if (this.toRect().contains(bonus.toRect().topLeft) ||
          this.toRect().contains(bonus.toRect().topCenter) ||
          this.toRect().contains(bonus.toRect().topRight)) {
        this.remove = true;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Either don't declare the list as `Components` or use a cast to `Bonus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`whereType`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Iterable/whereType.html) to filter on types. It's like `where` that just checks for a type, but it also ensures that the resulting iterable has that element type.

```dart
controller.components.whereType<Bonus>().forEach((bonus) {
  ... bonus.toRect ...
});
```

The Dart style guide [recommends](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-using-iterableforeach-with-a-function-literal) not using a function literal with `forEach`, use a for-loop instead:

```dart
for (var bonus in controller.components.whereType<Bonus>()) {
  ... bonus.toRect ...
}
```

If you are doing that anyway, you can also just do:

```dart
for (var component in controller.compenents) {
  if (component is Bonus) {
    .. component.toRect ...
  }
}
```

The type promotion from the `is` check will ensure that you can call `toRect`.
This very directly specifies what's going on, without creating unnecessary intermediate iterables.

Answer (score 2):

Could do:

```
.forEach((bonus) {
    Bonus bonus = bonus;
    .....
```

or

```
(controller.components.where((c) => c is Bonus) as List<Bonus>).forEach((bonus) {
```